# How do you render videos with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, video, awt, render

How do you render videos with Java Swing? This is my current code and i want to replace the image rendering with rendering a video. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class AuroraPanel extends JPanel {

    private JFrame master;

    public AuroraPanel(JFrame master) {
        this.master = master;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, master.getWidth(), 40);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 30, master.getWidth(), master.getHeight() - 30);
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/wat.png"));
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 30, this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(0, master.getHeight() - 350, master.getWidth(), master.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're really willing to figure out how to decode the video frames and audio, do the synchronisation required, as well as get involved in the playing audio frames - you don't.  No, seriously, Swing isn't well suited for it.  Most playback workflows work by rendering directly onto a surface of a heavy weight component, where as Swing makes use of "light weight" components (they don't have their own native peer).  Instead, you could look at things like VLC bindings for Swing/AWT, but remember, you're still dealing with the heavy weight components

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a combination of colour masking, window handle passing, and `vlc --drawable-hwnd=`, `mplayer -wid`, or similar.

You draw a big purple square someplace in your app. You then use some java hackery to obtain the underlying OS window handle of that window. You then use `ProcessBuilder` to fire up ffmpeg, passing in some of the more exotic parameters to say that it should draw on the pixels with the purple colour, in the window with handle XYZ. Some of these can't do the colour thing and just take over the entire window. This is somewhat problematic, as you'd have to then use AWT to get an OS-level window within a window.

As far as I know, this does not work on macs, due to macs not allowing apps to mess with windows they don't own unless they have been configured to be assistive apps in the security settings.

But it is an avenue to try, at least on windows and linux.

There are also projects like [JavaCV](https://github.com/teocci/Streaming-Player-Java) which use similar tricks (launch ffmpeg or similar under the hood).

Comment: Is there any other way of rendering videos in java swing? Im trying to make this work for all operating systems. Thx for ur help tho

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't. There's this thing called the JMF (Java Media Framework) but it hasn't seen updates for over a decade, so I highly doubt that'll work on anywhere near the 100% of platforms you want.